# asp.net mvc 5 admin route

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have HomeController.cs and AccountController.cs in Controller directory. I added new folder in Controller directory named "Admin" and in it I added DashboardController.cs

I want to /admin/dashboard to route to DashboardController unfortunately /admin/Home and /admin/Account will also route to their respective controller. I want that /admin/Home and /admin/Account will be 404. How do i do this?

here is my RouteConfig.cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Admin",
            url: "admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: I think that the proper way to do that is, using `areas` http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/dhananjay_kumar/archive/2015/11/25/areas-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Admin route, you need to replace `{controller}` with `dashboard` as seen below, that way it doesn't treat the next thing after the `/admin/` part in your URL as the controller.:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Admin",
        url: "admin/dashboard/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

The MVC routes are not mapped on the basis of folder structure. 
In your url ("admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}") the substring before the first / represents the name of your controller. In this case you are specifying that the request would be calling "AdminController" and not "DashboardController". Solution given by @Wellspring is correct here.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Hackerman in the comments. The right way to do this is by introducing an Admin area. This will automatically make a route for yoursite.com/admin pages.

To add the Admin area, right click on your web project, select Add > Area.

You then want to place your Dashboard controller and views in the corresponding folders of that Area.

Besides adding the area, you want to make it so your default route in RouteConfig.cs doesn't pull up the controllers on the Admin area. To do this you need to edit the Default route in your Route.config.cs. You want to add a namespace attribute on the call to MapPath and set the UseNamespaceFallback data token to false:

```
Route defaultRoute = routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new[] { typeof(HomeController).Namespace }
);
// this makes it so the route only looks for controllers under
// the namespace specified through the namespaces parameter
defaultRoute.DataTokens["UseNamespaceFallback"] = false;
```